# Trying to create a DECIMAL(1,1) within a MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, decimal

I have written a MySQL Trigger which updates average rating of a product when a new review is inserted. However the following database exception is thrown when an insert is made `Numeric value out of range`.

The column the value goes into is set as a `DECIMAL(1,1)`.

I have setup the following trigger but still get the error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_products_average_rating` AFTER INSERT ON  `reviews` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE products 
    SET average_rating = ( SELECT CAST( AVG( rating ) AS DECIMAL( 1, 1 ) ) 
    FROM reviews
    WHERE product_id = products.id ) 
WHERE id = NEW.product_id;
```

I was hoping the `AS DECIMAL(1,1)` would solve the issue but it does not.

I'm using MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Numeric value out of range" means the number is too big for the allocated spot for it.  DECIMAL(1,1) is a tiny allocation, so it's not surprising.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html):

> In a DECIMAL column declaration, the precision and scale can be (and
>   usually is) specified; for example:
>
> salary DECIMAL(5,2)
>
> In this example, 5 is the precision and 2 is the scale. The precision
>   represents the number of significant digits that are stored for
>   values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be
>   stored following the decimal point.
>
> Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value
>   with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the
>   salary column range from -999.99 to 999.99.

As you can see from this, DECIMAL(1,1) means you can store exactly one digit.  If you are trying to store more than one digit, it will be too big for that spot.

**EDIT**

To have 3.5, you need DECIMAL (2, 1).  That's because 3.5 has TWO digits in it and ONE decimal place.

Comment: The average rating will only ever be between 1 and 5. Hence `DECIMAL(1,1)`

Comment: @diggersworld Then just use INT (probably small int) and your problem will be solved.

Comment: But I want to allow for fractions between 1 and 5. i.e. 3.4, 2.6, 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL(1,1)` doesn't make sense. MySql documentation quoted by @spsc_tech explains it.
If you're counting average and it's results will be small numbers, and you want only 1 digit precision i suggest you to cast as `DECIMAL(2,1)`.
You'll have range from -9,9 to 9,9

Comment: The average rating will only ever be between 1 and 5. Hence `DECIMAL(1,1)`

Comment: sorry for mistake, i'd edited my answer. `DECIMAL(2,1)` will have range -9,9 to 9,9. It'll fit for you.